# Why does it say incorrect syntax when it should be right

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I'm currently trying to execute a query in Visual Studio to add a user to my database.
I've added the database to my Server Explorer and I right-clicked it and selected `New query`
In my tables, I have a table called `dbo.User` and I am trying to execute this one query.

```
INSERT INTO User (Username, Password, Color)
VALUES ('Craig', 'password', 'Green')
```

`Intellisense` even recognized `User` and for some reason `Password is highlighted as a keyword`

Why does it put a red line user `User` in `INSERT INTO User`  saying  `Incorrect syntax near 'User'`

Comment: `user` is a reserved word.  I don't know if that would cause the problem you are seeing, but using reserved words for identifier names is a bad practice.  You can see the list here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: As a general, when you're told it's wrong, it's wrong (but the error message may sometimes be unintuitive). I've never run into an issue where the compiler was wrong and I was right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User is a reserved keyword by SQL Server. To get around this, put keywords in brackets. Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO [User] (Username, Password, Color)
VALUES ('Craig', 'password', 'Green')
```

Comment: Oh my.. I should of known.. Thanks! I'll accept this answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped! Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Rename your table to something that is not a reserved word.  I usually name tables in the plural.  One reason is because plurals have fewer conflicts (`VALUES` comes to mind).  Another is because they contain multiple copies of the entity, so a plural seems appropriate.

So, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Color)
    VALUES ('Craig', 'password', 'Green');
```

The list of reserved words is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

I also strongly discourage you from storing free-text passwords in such a table.  You should be encoding the password when the user types it in, so your application can never see it.  Users often re-use passwords across multiple systems, so having free-text passwords *anywhere* is a security hole.